# Solving $2^b=3^b -1$ where b is a natural number

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Solving $2^b=3^b−1$  for natural b.

I tried factoring out $3^b-2^b$, but what next then? It's obviously 1, but I have no idea how to prove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a natural number $n$ it is $3^n\ge 2^n.$ If $n=0$ it is $3^0=2^0=1.$ If $n=1$ it is $3^1-2^1=1.$ If $n\ge 2$ it is $3^n-2^n= 3\cdot 3^{n-1}-2\cdot 2^{n-1}> 3^{n-1}-2^{n-1}\ge 1 $ (show it by induction). So, you have, that the only solution of

$$1=3^n-2^n$$

is $n=1.$